# PHP: Object in Object calling a Function

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to PHP OOP, but not so much to PHP, wanted to start learning.. and hit a few brick walls, but this one stumped me.. BUT since I can't find any questions anywhere on the web.. I can't find answers either..

So.. The Code.. I dumbed it down to its core problem, if I can understand that..

```
    <?php

class wallet {
    public $Money = 5;

    public function Add($mMoney) {
        $this->Money += $mMoney;
        echo "added $mMoney to Wallet";
        }
    public function take($mMoney) {
        $this->Money -= $nMoney;
        }
    public function check() {
        echo $this->Money;
        echo "Check?";
    } 

    public function __get($var) {
      echo "trying to get $var and Failing";

    }       

}

class person {
    public $Name;
    public $Wallet;
    public $Purse;
    public $Cash;

    public function __construct($name, $cash) {

        $this->Wallet = new wallet();
        $this->Purse = new wallet();
        $this->Name = $name;
        $this->Cash = $cash;
    }

    public function status() {
       echo "<br><table border = 1><tr><td>".$this->Name."</td><td> Wallet?</td><td> Purse </td></tr>
       <tr><td> $ ".$this->Cash."</td><td>".$this->checkWallet()."<td>22</td></tr></table>";

    }

    public function toWallet($toAdd)  {
       $this->Wallet->add($toAdd);

    }

    public function checkWallet() {
       echo $this->Wallet->check();

    }

}

$bob = new person ("Bob", 10);
$sarah = new person ("Sarah", 20);

$bob->status();
$sarah->status();

$bob->toWallet(10);

$bob->status();
$sarah->status();

?>
```

Why won't toWallet Work? Why can't I access $this->checkWallet()..

Comment: Won't work? Can't access? Please care to explain your problem, don't just drop your code here and wait it to get fixed.

Comment: Try writting the function name with a capital "A"  as in `$this->Wallet->Add($toAdd);`

Comment: Its on a Windows machine and doesn't care for Capitals or not,

Th point seems to be that the scope of the functions is far more difficult for me to understand than normal global or functional variables..

I was to understand by declaring the variable inside of a class, it can be referenced with $this.. but in this case.. it doesn't see it, either returning, no variable

Comment: I cut n pasted this so it runs complete, just copy paste its entirety to a blank php and run it..  Sorry to Alvaro, I felt this was the current norm for such a site.. Cut n Paste the problem so it displays for Anyone to Cut n paste it into a blank php file and run from their own PC to look at the problem and see it work or Not..

If you do this you will see that the 'add money to wallet' is not working.. the idea of an in-scope class inside of a class unable to run the 2nd class functions .. sorry it was not so obvious on its own, I thought it was a rookie mstake and anyone would spot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why ToWallet won't work is because the function thinks the echo from the Add is the return value. (Which is obviously a string and is useless in calculation). There needs to be a return command for the mMoney variable. Try typing something like this in the Add function

```
public function Add($mMoney) {
        $this->Money += $mMoney;
        echo "added $mMoney to Wallet";
        return $mMoney;
        }
```

I don't know how nobody else spotted that.

Comment: Well, Thats probably interesting, but I don't want to return the Money back to anything else.. 

I'm trying to understand the nature of Objects, and Objects that Hold Objects..

Here we have an Object Person, with an Object Wallet, I want a function to add Money to the Object Wallet, from the object person, and then I want to be able to access the Wallet to see how much Money is in the Wallet.. It matter not about the example, purely how to 'see' the information inside the object which is itself inside of another object..

Comment: Ahh, Thanks Redelman, It was the return but not for Money, but for check.. I was attempting to get it on screen, not to the other object

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone who comes across this in the future.. Heres the Solution:

First: When you have an Object, don't echo or print the data to the screen, return it to the parent object to do that for you,

Second: Double check that all Variables are either function only i.e. $wallet, or are the objects variables $this->wallet  because even though I was staring at the code for hours, I couldn't see that this was not the same variable..

new to OOP, what a mind-mess